# How send one bit(no byte) through ethernet port

Tags: c#, sockets, ethernet

I am writing a networking application.speed is very important in my application, I send byte through Ethernet port and speed is approximately 350 us in this case, see below figure:

http://i59.tinypic.com/2zgu8id.jpg

I want to send bit through Ethernet port to reduce speed , i have below question:

1- Will it affect in speed? How to do it? There is no such thing in msdn website.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

2- Do is better to use many windows Application for many send byte ?

Comment: Sending it bit per bit instead of byte per byte does not necessarily increase the speed. Also multiple apllications that work in the same network will also not necessarily increase the speed. I recommend to compress the files you want to send first, so you have less data to send and therefore it will be sent faster and then the receiving end has to decompress the data again. This means more processing power needed by your application but less time needed t osend and receive data.

Comment: Smallest allocation unit is byte, so you can't send just a bit

Comment: Suppose you could. How much faster would that be? and what good use will it have?

Comment: Why doesn't `Stopwatch` start just before the `SendTo`?

Comment: Ethernet deals with packets, not bits. It doesn't send single bytes either, it creates and sends packets. Sending less data will **reduce** throughput as it will result in **more packets**. Finally, Ethernet settings are controlled by the **driver**. Sockets and C# (or any other language) have no notion of them and don't need to

Comment: Regardless of size, you're not really going to get any faster. What's killing you is latency, not bandwidth (although your suggestion will lower the effective bandwidth as well, as others have pointed out) - if you need something with latency reliably lower than about 5ms, you need to use the proper tools - that means no .NET, no ethernet and no (desktop) Windows; it's well within the realm of a proper real-time OS, and you'll be better served by using a simple RS232 link.

Comment: thanks MeAndSomeRandoms , Amit: this application is for line scan camera in 600 fps , therefore speed is important in real time process

Comment: @Luaan I think you go too far and make the wrong assumptions. Stock exchanges don't use serial lines, they use fiber to achieve microsecond latencies. Factories and even gunships use Ethernet to control robots and guns that weigh tons and move *fast*.

Comment: @mohammad2050 not exactly. In multimedia applications, jitter is bad, consistent delays are *not*. As long as the frames arrive in sequence and at the correct intervals, it doesn't matter if the first frame arrives a bit slow. In fact, it's better to drop a late frame to avoid delays for the next one. None of this is new though, did you check how others do the same thing?

Comment: Luaan , in your opinion Raspberry Pi is appropriate tools? in my opinion ethernet is better of rs232

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos They did use serial lines before fiber, though :) And factories and gunships usually have other considerations than raw latency - the actuators have delays far longer than the network latency, and in any case, you can simply offset by any measured latency and be done with it. They also don't tend to use multi-tasking OS. I was pointing out the absurdity of what the OP is considering and trying to do - it doesn't really make *sense*.

Comment: @mohammad2050 What are you trying to do? The original question has little to do with what you describe in the comments.

Comment: @mohammad2050 No, not really. But then again, I don't think you really care about latencies so low. As Panagiotis noted, you don't care about raw latencies, you care about stutter. If you know there's always a latency of 5ms, you can simply assume that everything is 5ms old. Human reaction times vary wildly, but 200ms latencies are fine for most purposes, with the lower end being somewhere around 20ms. The major exception to this is sound, harmonies in particular - definitely not sight. It's kind of hard to process visual information for the brain :)

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos , i want to read data of camera and send output command to other device

Comment: @mohammad2050 again, this is nothing new. This is industrial automation and you should check for relevant sources, not in SO. Anyway, it's the *camera driver's* job to deliver frames at the rate you need, not something you should do in application code. A Raspberry Pi *can* control devices based on camera input - industrial automation uses *far less powerful* machines. You need to find the proper camera driver though

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos , no i have not any problem in read frame data of camera , my problem is large time for process data by windows application , this one send time is 350 us that is good , but i want to send 40 output command that become approximately 16 ms that is bad, good time for send 40 output for me is 2ms. i have loss frame data for large time

Comment: The point is that you want to batch those commands together. Instead of sending 40 separate commands, send just one batch command that contains all of those. Then you only deal with the latency once for little extra cost (*then* you can easily devise a scheme that allows you to pack the commands tighlty).

Comment: @ Luaan yes my point is it, thanks

Comment: @mohammad2050 Instead of processing frames one at a time, consider using TPL DataFlow to process the data as a stream. This will allow you to use a different thread for each processing step. DataFlow was created for exactly this kind of applications

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos ,
ok and many thanks for information,so i use TPL DataFlow to process the data as a stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with each message you send, a header is included, containing for instance the destination address. Without this information, your message will never arrive at its destination.

A typical IPv4 header is 20 bytes. So even if it would be possible, 8 bits is not 700% more data than 1 bit, but 33% more.

Since each message includes such a header, you should try to include as much as possible data to reduce the number of messages you need to send.

If this answer does not help, you might want to include your ultimate goal, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: my ultimate goal is to read data of line scan camera and process on data and send output , i have not any problem in read frame data of camera ,  my problem is large time for process data by windows application , this one send time is 350 us that is good , but i want to send 40 output command that become approximately 16 ms that is bad, good time for send 40 output for me is 2ms. i have loss frame data for large time

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to send a single bit then - you can only gain from sending more data at once. Also, does the order in which those commands are received matter? (With UDP they can arrive in any order)

Comment: ok and many thanks,so i use TPL DataFlow to process the data as a stream.